# winrm not found error for ansible-packer provisioning

Tags: python, ansible, gitlab, packer, packer-builder

I am using gitlab for deployment and Packer for image automation and ansible for configuration management for creating windows image.
when I am trying to call ansible provisioner from packer it is throwing below error:

```
<default> Attempting python interpreter discovery
[WARNING]: Unhandled error in Python interpreter discovery for host default:
Using module file /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible/modules/command.py
winrm or requests is not installed: No module named 'winrm'
Pipelining is enabled.
fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {
"msg": "winrm or requests is not installed: No module named 'winrm'"
```

also I am getting below ansible configs in output :

```
ansible-playbook 2.10.5
config file = None
configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
python version = 3.9.5 (default, Nov 24 2021, 21:19:13)
 No config file found; using defaults
setting up inventory plugins
setting up inventory plugins
host_list declined parsing /tmp/packer-provisioner-ansible87uu7yu as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /tmp/packer-provisioner-ansible87uu7yu as it did not pass its verify_file() method
```

Can someone please suggest where it is getting stuck.. since I am already using winrm.ps1 for winrm installation before this ansible runs.. but it is still failing..
also .. I am not sure if ansible is failing for python or winrm

Comment: Can you confirm `winrm` and `requests` are installed in `/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages` ?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.. I added an step to install pywinrm[kerberos]==0.4.1 in the base image.. which helped me install winrm